# Kafka topic constantly rolling new log segments, no overrides, logfiles tiny

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I have a kafka topic that is constantly rolling new log segments, when the log.segment.bytes is set to 512 megabytes in the broker config. Most of the log files average at 5-10 kilobytes.

If I look at the topic, I can't see any overrides. And even if I create the overrides and set segment.bytes to whatever, it will still follow with the same behaviour.

I am a bit puzzled on this. Any ideas on where to look next?

```
root@utilitypod-985642408:/opt/kafka/bin# ./kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper 
zookeeper:2181 --describe --topic dev.com.redacted.redacted.services.redacted.priceStream.notification
Topic:dev.com.redacted.redacted.services.redacted.priceStream.notification   PartitionCount:3        ReplicationFactor:3     Configs:segment.bytes=536870912,segment.index.bytes=53687091,flush.messages=20000,flush.ms=600000
    Topic: dev.com.redacted.redacted.services.redacted.priceStream.notification  Partition: 0    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1,2,0 Isr: 2,1,0
    Topic: dev.com.redacted.redacted.services.redacted.priceStream.notification  Partition: 1    Leader: 2       Replicas: 2,0,1 Isr: 0,2,1
    Topic: dev.com.redacted.redacted.services.redacted.priceStream.notification  Partition: 2    Leader: 0       Replicas: 0,1,2 Isr: 1,0,2
```

That's my Kafka broker (which is running in a k8s cluster but that shouldn't matter) config:

```
log.dirs=/var/lib/kafka/data/topics
num.partitions=3
default.replication.factor=3
min.insync.replicas=2
auto.create.topics.enable=true
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=4

############################# Server Basics #############################
# The id of the broker. This must be set to a unique integer for each broker.
#init#broker.id=#init#
#init#broker.rack=#init#

#listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092
listeners=OUTSIDE://:9094,PLAINTEXT://:9092
#init#advertised.listeners=OUTSIDE://#init#,PLAINTEXT://:9092
listener.security.protocol.map=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,SSL:SSL,SASL_PLAINTEXT:SASL_PLAINTEXT,SASL_SSL:SASL_SSL,OUTSIDE:PLAINTEXT
inter.broker.listener.name=PLAINTEXT
num.network.threads=2
num.io.threads=8
socket.send.buffer.bytes=1048576
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=1048576
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600
queued.max.requests=16
message.max.bytes=1000000
offsets.topic.replication.factor=3
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=3
transaction.state.log.min.isr=2
log.flush.interval.messages=20000
log.retention.hours=168
log.segment.bytes=536870912
log.flush.scheduler.interval.ms=2000
log.cleaner.enable=false
log.retention.check.interval.ms=60000
zookeeper.connect=zookeeper:2181
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000
group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0
delete.topic.enable=true
```

Comment: Can you post the config of the topic ? For example the output of:
`./bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper ZOOKEEPER --describe --topic TOPIC`

Comment: which version of kafka you are using , might be timebased rollover is getting triggered , check the jira  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-4099 ,

Comment: @LijuJohn I'm using 1.0.0

Comment: @MickaelMaison added to the question, thx

Comment: What timestamps are you sending? Retention is 168 hours from right now

Comment: @DmitryMinkovsky it was that. We were timestamping using nanotime. Feel free to add an answer and I'll accept it! Thanks.

Comment: Great to hear. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible that you are sending records with timestamps that are in the past, beyond the `log.retention.hours` (or `.ms`, etc) setting?

If so, your records will almost immediately be deleted. As you describe, the segments will be rolled. The last offset will remain, but it will equal the end offset--meaning the logs will be empty.